# Delete 30 days older files based on the date in the filename

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I received files with names in the csv format
Example: 
     I want to remove the files which are older than 30 days based on the date in the filename

doesn't seem to help me much .

Do not want to use `find mtime +30 days` as i want to schedule every 30 days file needs to be removed based on the date in file name.

Comment: The last claim about `find` not being usable does not really make sense to me.

Comment: find YourDir -type f -mtime +30 -name "*.csv" -delete . it is based on the file modified date . i want to extract date from the filename and delete 30 days file s.

Comment: Okay, so what's the relevance of the removal only taking place every 30 days?

Comment: It would be easy to use Python.

Comment: I would like to schedule the deltion every day . so if I go with find + mtime method . if the scrupt didnt execute or called via my application . there will be some expected error of file not being deleted . so to avoid that . we are planning to remove based on the filename

Comment: python works well for me . do you have the script to do in python ?

Comment: You could use `date +%s` to convert dates to timestamps you'll be able to compare. Produce the timestamp for 30 days ago, the one of the dates from your filenames and use that comparison as a filter. (python would most probably be better : using `Date` objects avoid a lot of hassle and it's going to be more performant)

Comment: :source $ ls -ltr | awk -F_ '{print $3}' | awk -F. '{print $1}' | date +%s
:source $ date 20180301
date: invalid date '20180301'
source $ date -d 20180301
Thu Mar  1 00:00:00 CST 2018

Comment: Yeah, when omitting the `-d`/`--date` option the date parameter is expected in a specific format (`MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, based on arithmetic comparison of timestamps, should work :

```
keep_ts=$(date --date="30 days ago" +%s)
for file in $yourDir/*.csv; do
    file_ts=$(date --date="$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f3 | cut -d. -f1)" +%s)
    if [ "$file_ts" -lt "$keep_ts" ]; then
        rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Nice ! Btw I used `cut` out of habit, but your parameter expansion `${f%%.*}` / `${d##*_}` would probably be better (no extra process spawned).

Comment: Let me know try that out . :) Thanks for the help

Comment: ${d##*_} this helped me to extract the date alone .